# Update query in DB2 with values from second table where multiple entries exist for the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I have two tables

**Table 1**

```
ID    SELECTEDNAME 
101     ______________
```

**Table 2**

```
ID    NAME    UPDATEDATE 
101     JOHN     02-22-17 
101     RITA     02-23-17
```

In **Table 1** `ID` is PK. My requirement is to update the `SELECTEDNAME` column in **Table 1** by extracting the `name` from **Table 2**

The name should be extracted from Table 2 such that the corresponding `UPDATEDATE` should be the latest.

For example, in Table2, I need a query to compare the `UPDATEDATE` in `between` the two entries for `ID` 1 and get the `name` as RITA as the `UPDATEDATE` is latest

There could be more than two entries for a given `ID` in the table.

Comment: What have you tried already? Try writing the query yourself and then come to StackOverflow once you feel like you're on the right path.

Comment: So, MySQL or DB2?

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
update t1
inner join (select t2.id,max(t2.updatedate) as updatedate
 from t2  
 group by t2.id) t2max on t2max.id=t1.id
 inner join t2 on t2.id=t2max.id
 SET t1.selectedname=t2.name
 WHERE t2.updatedate=t2max.updatedate
```

Comment: Is this a MySQL or DB2 answer?

Comment: Hi Jahrl , This is Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 version :

```
UPDATE table1 f0
SET f0.SELECTEDNAME=
( 
    SELECT f1.name 
    FROM table2 f1 INNER JOIN 
                    (
                    SELECT f2.id, max(f2.updatedate) maxdate 
                    FROM table2 f2 
                    GROUP BY f2.id

                    ) f3 ON (f1.id, f1.updatedate)=(f3.id, f3.maxdate)
    WHERE f1.id=f0.id
    FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY
)
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * FROM table2 f1 
    WHERE f1.id=f0.id
)
```